# Unable to add browser control in Visual Studio Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webbrowser-control

I want to make a browser in visual studio and every tutorial so far used a webbrowser from the tool box but i can't be able to find it, i'm using visual studio 2019

Comment: what is your current app .net framework version? If it is .net core app, I suggest that you can try to change into .net framework app. Also, I recommend that you can update your vs2019 to the latest version. If the above advice is not working, you can report a problem in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home).

Answer (score 0):

- Right click toolbox
- "Choose items..."
- ".NET Framework Components"
- Scroll down to "WebBrowser"
- Check checkbox

Comment: it was already checked but it still wouldn't show up and when i clicked show all i wasn't able to drag it in